# Unsupported Operand type - Divide seconds to minutes

Tags: python, time, operands

This is the code I have:

```
start = time()
model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.3, epochs=2, batch_size=16, verbose=1, callbacks=[es, mc])
print('Training time in seconds: %.2f' % (time()-start)/60)
```

I need to divide my seconds to minutes (using /60). However, there is an operand error.

Error:

> ---> 20 print('Training time in seconds: %.2f' % (time()-start)/60) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another pair of parenthesis around your time calculation. Currently, it's formatting the string  with just `time() - start` and then trying to divide on the formatted string

```
print('Training time in seconds: %.2f' % ((time() - start) / 60))
```